# How to store agents and its' parameters in a 2 dimensional collection in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a population of agents (called products) that has multiple parameters of different types. The parameters are "amount" of type int and the other is "location" which is a location on the GIS map. Now I would like to store these agents in a collection when they enter an enter block. Does anyone know how to do this? What type of collection could I use and how do I define the elements?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag in a collection, keep the default `ArrayList` type and set the content type to your agent type.

In the `Enter` block's "on enter", write `myCollection.add(agent)`

That is all :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The only problem with this method is that I later want to sort the order based on their GISlocation stored in "location". I'm not sure if with your method I can iterate/sort over the parameters stored in the agents or can I? If not, are there other possibilities to put them into a list?

Comment: This is core Java functionality, search for "sort ArrayList by" and "Java comparator". Also, please flag answer as "useful" (next to the answer) so others with similar issues find this easier in the future :)

Comment: And feel free to open new issues with follow-up questions (SOF does not work like a forum, it is a Q&A place, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow )